# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Für die nächsten Stunden" und "In den nächsten Stunden"?

Tags: preposition

Satz:

"Nach dem Unterricht ging sie nach Hause und machte **für die nächsten Stunden / in den nächsten Stunden** ihre Hausaufgaben"

Mein Test sagt, beide Versionen sind richtig. Aber ich verstehe nicht was die Bedeutungen / Unterschiede sind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Für die nächsten Stunden" ist eine Angabe darüber, wofür die nächsten Stunden gebraucht/genutzt werden, "in den nächsten Stunden" ist eine Angabe eines Zeitintervalls, innerhalb dessen etwas stattfindet, ohne daß das Zeitintervall vollständig genutzt werden müßte oder nichts anderes parallel oder zu einem anderen Zeitpunkt innerhalb des Intervalls gemacht werden könnte.

Wenn ein Friseur sagte "wenn Sie in den nächsten 2 Stunden kommen, können wir Ihre Dauerwelle machen", dann bedeutete dies ein Zeitfenster, in dem noch Kapazitäten frei wären oder in dem noch genug Restzeit bis zum Schließen des Friseurladens bestünde, wenn der Kunde in diesem Zeitfenster einträfe.  Sagte ein Friseur hingegen "wenn Sie für die nächsten 2 Stunden kommen, können wir Ihre Dauerwelle machen", hieße das, daß man umgehend kommen solle und dann 2 Stunden beim Friseur verbringen werde.

Comment: super, gut geholfen. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Fantastische Antwort, aber hat jemand eine Ahnung, warum user49041 nun schon wieder weg ist?

Answer (score 7):

> Für die nächsten Stunden

beschreibt, dass die Tätigkeit **über die gesamte Dauer** (die nächsten Stunden) aufgeübt wird.

---

> In den nächsten Stunden

beschreibt, dass die Tätigkeit **zu einem Zeitpunkt innerhalb** der Dauer des Zeitraums (den nächsten Stunden) ausgeübt wird.

Answer (score 7):

> in den nächsten Stunden

impliziert auch (zusätzlich zu @choXer's Erklärung), dass der Vorgang danach abgeschlossen ist, sie hat also all ihre Hausaufgaben gemacht. Bei

> für die nächsten Stunden

ist das nicht zwangsläufig der Fall, sie könnte auch nur einen Teil ihrer Hausaufgaben gemacht haben.

Da es im Kontext um Unterricht geht, könnten mit "Stunden" aber auch "Unterrichtsstunden" gemeint sein. In diesem Fall würde der Satz aussagen **wofür** sie die Hausaufgaben gemacht hat (für die nächsten [Unterrichts]Stunden). Das könnte sie dann z.B. auch innerhalb von 5 Minuten gemacht haben.

Comment: Fein beobachtet: *für die nächsten Schulstunden*, im ersten Moment gar nicht naheliegend, aber wenn man's erst mal gesehen hat...